# Добавление VK API в Android

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Проблема при использовании VK API, а именно при подключении библиотеки. Работаю в Android Studio. Добавил библиотеку в проект. Но когда прописываю в манифесте:

`<activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKOpenAuthActivity" />`

Студия не видит класс `VKOpenAuthActivity`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Посмотрите файл build.gradle, там нужно добавить стороку:

```
compile project('vksdk_library')
```

После подключения модуля в проект, указывайте его в gradle.